# MVVM Framework for MonoDroid?

Tags: frameworks, mvvm, binding, command, xamarin.android

Is there a MVVM-framework for MonoDroid already? Or is MonoDroid able to do binding of Porperties and Commands by itself maybe? (like MVVM Light Toolkit for WPF/Silverlight/WP7 for example)

Answer (score 4):

No MVVM yet, but there is MonoCross, which is an MVC-based framework currently, with plans to move it to a MVVM pattern type:
[MonoCross](http://code.google.com/p/monocross/)

Comment: I've recently pushed an mvvm variant of monocross to http://github.com/slodge/mvvmcross - its got some initial databinding support for both droid and touch.