# MVVM Light Toolkit on Mono/MonoDroid?

Tags: mvvm, mono, toolkit, xamarin.android

is there a possibility to run the Galasoft MVVM Light Toolkit on Mono/Monodroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVVM Light Toolkit uses a number of interfaces in the WindowsBase.dll of .Net that might not be implemented by mono.  As the result shows, it cannot be used especially because the RelayCommand depends on the [CommandManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.aspx) of WPF.

You can run [MoMA](http://mono-project.com/MoMA) to determine the potential issues.

[image: Top Level Result]

Here is another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727719/mvvm-framework-for-monodroid) with an answer, which appears to be [monocross](http://code.google.com/p/monocross/) (not MVVM though).

Comment: Just an update on this - the latest portable class libraries in vs2012 make sharing Mvvm code more possible - and there are also at least a couple of Mvvm projects for monotouch/monodroid - see https://github.com/RobertKozak/MonoMobile.Views, https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross and https://github.com/follesoe/FlightsNorway